# Not able to debug javascripts after internet explorer update

Tags: internet-explorer

My internet explorer got auto updated in windows7 and debugging tools have now the new interface. Now I am not able to see START DEBUGGING button in the scripts tab and confused how to start debugging. I was very stick to the old debugging tools interface. Please tell me where is the start debuging button located in the new debugging tools UI of internet explorer.

Thanks in advance, for any prompt help

Comment: which version? i'm assuming 11? this should catch you up to speed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ie/bg182326(v=vs.85)

Comment: There is no button. Your breakpoints will automatically get hit once your page is reloaded or you cause the script to execute like clicking a button.

Comment: yeah it is version 11. what chris said makes sense after going through msdn page refered by albert. But the breake points are not getting hit automatically.The application which I am working on is using Frameset and i have set breakpoints in the scripts refered from each frame.May be these new debugging tools having compatablity issues with frameset refered scripts,or may be I am missing some IE settings.Finally if I am not able to sort this out by tommorow, i will have to rollback IE udate or windows update, if I am correct. :)

Comment: Guys, Now I am able to debug my scripts, but I am not able to see run button which used to run my own javascript commands. There used to be a multiline textbox, where we would type javascript line and hit run button to see the results. Please help

Comment: @user3075417 Those buttons are still there: http://i.imgur.com/HYNieZk.png. You can also use keyboard shortcuts, like `Enter` and `Ctrl+Alt+M` to run commands, or go into multi-line mode. Just make sure you're either on the `console` panel (`Ctrl+2`), or you have turned on the console from within another panel (`Ctrl+\``).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt help. My issues are resolved